# Power BI Matrix. Show Percentage of grand total even when filtered

Tags: powerbi

I have a column of total sales that I need to put in a matrix, by state and quarter. With each showing the percentage of the numbers to the grand total.

(not real data)

```
    Q1    Q2    Q3   Q4
```

MA      12%   15%   19%   9%

TX      30%   25%   23%   42%

CT      16%   43%   7%    21%

GA      7%    13%   22%   32%

(rest of states)

This works fine, until it is filtered and the values change. If I filter on just Texas it changes the values to be 100% of each column. How can I set it up to be able to filter and keep the values from changing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - but posting the answers for others:

SALES PCT =
VAR SALES =
SUM(Sales_Table[SALES_COLUMN])
VAR AllSales =
SUMX(
ALL(Sales_Table),
Sales_Table[SALES_COLUMN]
)
RETURN
DIVIDE(Sales,AllSales)

Be sure to double check format of column - this defaulted to a whole number for me, and showed all 0 to start